# FDISK Logical Partition

Tags: partitioning, ext4, fdisk

I have tried to create a logical partition via Fdisk for a flash drive. The problem is that I choose the option -n to create a partition, of course , and fdisk gives me only two options "extended and primary". However, I want an option for logical partitions. Moreover, in a topic in the forum, a guy is able to choose logical partition option instead of extended.

The topic's link:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1659376

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to create a Logical partition, you must first create an Extended "partition". As stated in the forum post, an Extended partition is just a container, not an actual partition. This Extended container is what contains the Logical partitions.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying this using the console command fdisk, you may have more luck using the graphical tool GParted instead.  I believe it will take care of the logical/extended flags for you, or at the very least will make it obvious which you need to use.

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/

Comment: Thank you sir for your attention but I have to use command line :)

Comment: In which case you can also use cfdisk, which is still console mode but is easier to decipher.